Update `commitizen` questions
In my Vue Js project I am using commitizen
When I do yarn cz I get all questions:
? Select the type of change that you're committing: (Use arrow keys)
❯ feat:     A new feature 
  fix:      A bug fix 
  docs:     Documentation only changes 
  style:    Changes that do not affect the meaning of the code (white-space, formatting, missing semi-colons, etc) 
  refactor: A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature 
  perf:     A code change that improves performance 
  test:     Adding missing tests or correcting existing tests 

I want to change the prefix and description for some of the options.
How do I create a setting file to update the base configuration of this tool?

It doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, but Adapters hints at what you need to do.
